# How to maintain divs in line with Zurb Foundation 3 framework

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a 12 column row, but I need to get a series of div blocks (4 div containers)within in a row to respond and not stack until it hits the appropriate breakpoint. Right now, as the browser goes smaller, the divs begin to stack.

```
Basically I have 4 divs. They need to be in a row. 
[div1] [div2] [div3] [div4]

But when I shrink the browser I see:
[div1] [div2] [div3]
[div4]
```

Each div has an image within them.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns center">
    <div class="button-container">
      <div class="calendar-container left hide-for-small">
        <img src="images/poc-calendar.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="search-container left">
        <img src="images/poc-button-search.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="submit-container left">
        <img src="images/poc-button-submit.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="social-container left hide-for-small">
        <img src="images/poc-social.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using display: inline and display: inline-block for the individual divs as well as the .button-container.

Here is my latest styles for this:

```
div.button-container {
    margin-top: 18px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

div.calendar-container {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

div.search-container {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

div.submit-container {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

div.legend-container {
    height: 86px;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be that after you have shrunk the viewport enough to pop the [div4]
under [div1] is to put in a media query that will reduce/remove margin/padding.

Comment: I ended up scaling the divs (1-4) via percentages ... basically, force scaling. I feel like Foundation should do this, just not applying the proper class, etc.